# How to query all the new tags created last week from Stack Exchange data Explorer?

Tags: sql, stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I want to [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) SO new tags created during last week.
We have tables Posts,Tags, PostTags (leave out TagSynonyms for now).

Tags doesn't have CreationDate so we probably need to use join with min(Post.CreationDate)

```
last week = getdate() - 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will produce a list of **posts** that the tags are created the past week. The `JOIN` between the tables is only to bring information. The `WHERE` clause would exclude tags which have been used prior to the 7 days.

The subquery will produce a list of unique tag IDs that where used in the past. Following your last week example in question, the formula is created by using the `DATEDIFF` function.

```
SELECT PostTags.PostId, PostTags.TagId, Tags.TagName, Posts.CreationDate
FROM PostTags
JOIN Posts
ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
JOIN Tags
ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.Id
WHERE PostTags.TagId NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT PostTags.TagId AS OlderTags
  FROM PostTags
  JOIN Posts
  ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
  WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CreationDate, GETDATE()) > 7)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @JoPapou13, if I also want to to it distinct on TagId, now can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could SELECT DISTINCT A.TagId, A.TagName FROM (Query in answer)A